# rclpy: Set parameter value before defining a node

Tags: rclpy

I have a node like this:

```
class MyNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        descriptor = ParameterDescriptor(name="param",
                                         type=ParameterType.PARAMETER_STRING)

        self.declare_parameter("param", None, descriptor)
```

How can I set a value for param "param" in a test before or while instantiating the node? I can do it from a launch file and I can do it from the cli but is there a ways to write a test that simply does this:

```
# set value for the node parameter

node = MyNode()

# add test stuff for the node
```